# Postman Newman htmlextra raport installation error

Tags: node.js, npm, postman-newman

I have problem with installations errors when i use ..

npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra

I don't realy know how to solve this problem.
Its happend olny with htmlextra raports when i install htlm raports its work normaly.

---

C:\Users\MW\Newman_testy>npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
'CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN deprecated highlight.js@9.18.5: Support has ended for 9.x series. Upgrade to @latest
npm WARN deprecated gulp-header@1.8.12: Removed event-stream from gulp-header
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
C:\Users\MW\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman-reporter-htmlextra -> C:\Users\MW\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman-reporter-htmlextra\bin\htmlextra.js

> highlight.js@9.18.5 postinstall C:\Users\MW\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman-reporter-htmlextra\node_modules\highlight.js
> node deprecated.js

npm WARN newman-reporter-htmlextra@1.21.0 requires a peer of newman@^5.1.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291
npm ERR! file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! highlight.js@9.18.5 postinstall: `node deprecated.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291 ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the highlight.js@9.18.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MW\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-20T12_08_29_915Z-debug.log

---

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet, I switch  win to mac and its works find.